# Output current week number within month PHP

Tags: php

I have a PHP script to identify the current month and current week within that month.

For today, it *should* output **501** (i.e. 5th week of the 1st month), however right now it outputs **101**.

Can someone explain why this is the case and how I can resolve? I feel I'm missing something obvious.

```
<?php 
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");

function weekOfMonthFunction($date) {
    $firstOfMonth = date("Y-m-01", strtotime($date));
    return intval(date("W", strtotime($date))) - intval(date("W", strtotime($firstOfMonth)));
}

$week = weekOfMonthFunction($date2);
$week = $week + 1;
$month = date("m");
$week_month = $week.$month;

echo $week_month;
```

Comment: `Undefined variable: date2`

Comment: @0stone0 In order to get this to work, what should `$date2` equal? I did try `$date2 = date("Y-m-d");` but this failed.

Comment: I'm surprised you're getting 101, since with today's date I'm getting -4801. That's because 2021-01-01 is technically in the 53rd week of 2020, not the first week of 2021

Comment: @aynber Yep, I've been getting some strange results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");

function weekOfMonth() {
    $now = time();
    $week = date('W', $now);
    $firstWeekOfMonth = date('W', strtotime(date('Y-m-01', $now)));
    return 1 + ($week < $firstWeekOfMonth ? $week : $week - $firstWeekOfMonth);
}

$week = weekOfMonth();
$week_month = $week . date("m");

echo $week_month;
```

> 501

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBNC4JAEIbv@ysGCVop@7im4alb0TE6SeiIUu4s60hQ9NtNXaWk9rLw7sMz76zOdF0Hoc60SC6MUYLppbpxxHmBD1IYlcjS2VWGNC73pBJSjusLkVYq5pwU3BGvx/RAijPpwlNAcyaK7rCF1iEbuItarsnaIXJ6ms47aHhMc1Py6WMagSUbps5ls7NXeKv1YHB7h0GujII1zEDaYcEfb9gX2fS398s0vpcQQ9/Rer6No6LvaKGF7eoU3cdgnBF8YX5dvwE)

Answer (score 1):

You've fixed the date to `Y-m-01` instead of `Y-m-d` from the parameter date.

How about this alternative?

```
function weekOfMonthFunction($date) {
    list($d, $m) = explode('-', date("d-m", strtotime($date)));
    return intval(ceil($d/7).str_pad($m, 1, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT));
}

echo weekOfMonthFunction('2021-01-25'); //Give 401
echo weekOfMonthFunction('2020-01-29'); //Gives 501
```

Explanation:
Date of month divided by 7 rounded up to get week number prepended to month number with a padded 0